# Import "tensorflow.compat.v2" could not be resolved

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I met the tensorflow.compat.v2 import error as indicated in the title. I installed tensorflow 2.13.1, keras 2.13.1 and Python 3.11.5 on Windows 10 machine. When I was trying to import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf, I was told this error. Furthermore, when I was trying to run my file, I was told another error as shown below:
[image]

Can you help me solve the issue? If so, I would appreciate it. I don't wanna change the version of Python as changing the Python version seemed to lead to more errors.

Comment: show the code that triggered the error, show the packages installed and their versions. don't screenshot error messages. paste them here as text.

Comment: It seems that this code line caused the error: from keras.src.backend import cast